# How to hide identical divs, while displaying just one?

Tags: jquery

I have select with a conditional sub select, which displays the selected sub select as a div.
However, each div has the same class name, which I can't change. The div inside each identical div can have a unique id. How do I display the selected content while hiding all other divs? This description probably doesn't make sense - see [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/F6ZWF/16/).

```
<div class="container">
<div id="two" class="phone">Content one</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div id="one" class="phone">Content two</div>
</div>
```

I can hide the content of unselected divs, but not the outer div with class name .container. The div I want to display also has the class name .container.

How to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic DOM: Every element in a DOM tree has a parent node. If you wanted to (say) hide the `one` node's parent, then you'd simply do

```
$('#one').parent().hide();
```

That'd apply to the `div.container` which contains the `one` node. If you have multiple layers of parent nodes you need to traverse, e.g.

```
<div class="container">
   <div>
      <div>
         <div id="one">...</div>
 etc...
```

then `$('#one').parent('.container')` will search back up through all the parent nodes to find a matching node, and accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Use `.parent('.container')` instead.

Comment: You guys are fast!
$('#one').parent().hide(); works but needs to be more dynamic. How should I use .parent('.container')?

Comment: What if I have a long list of divs - $('#selector').parent('.container') - they will all have the .container div, but isn't there a more dynamical way to get around this instead of having to list each of them as a selector?

Comment: jquery allows `$('#one, #two, #three, ...)` type stuff as well. Though, I think you're trying to get at wanting to hide ALL of the .containers except the one that's got your "please show" div. in that case, you could simply hide all .container divs, then show the one that has your #one

Comment: or even `$('.container').not(document.getElementById('one')).hide();` might work, as per the jquery docs: http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: You are getting there. But I would rather test if the selected `.container div` has id `$('#' +selectedmodel)` - if not, hide it. If it does, display its parent `.container div`, but hide all others.

Comment: I have been trying with something like this:
`$('.container').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'selectedmodel')
       $('#' +selectedmodel).parent('.container').show();
        });`
but it's not working as intended. Any ideas?

Comment: I managed to figure it out: `$(".container").hide();
        $('#' +selectedmodel).parent('.container').show();`. I have updated the jsFiddle in my initial question to this working tolution.